# Joomla 2.5 module won't upload media folder

Tags: joomla, module

How do I upload a css file in my Joomla module?  The manifest file is:

```
<files>
    <filename>mod_wforcsliderresz.xml</filename>
    <filename module="mod_wforcsliderresz">mod_wforcsliderresz.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <folder>tmpl</folder>
</files>    
<media folder="media" destination="mod_wforcsliderresz">
        <folder>css4c</folder>
</media>   
<languages>
    <!-- Any language files included with the module -->
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_wforcsliderresz.ini</language>
</languages>
```

I can overcome the problem by uploading the css directly but that's no good as a long term solution.
I've checked through FTP for the newly created folder media/mod_wforcsliderresz/css but there is no mod_wforcsliderresz subfolder within media.

I also tried to add a cssstfff above the tmpl definition but that wouldn't work.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think your css folder

`css4c`  (if it exists) , is uploaded to`media/media/mod_wforcsliderresz/css4c`

Note that it's `media/media`.If you would remove

`folder="media"` from `<media folder="media" destination="mod_wforcsliderresz">`

then it would be in `media/mod_wforcsliderresz/css4c`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<media folder="media" destination="mod_wforcsliderresz">
        <folder>css4c</folder>
</media>
```

to this:

```
<media folder="mod_wforcsliderresz">
        <folder>css4c</folder>
</media>
```

Comment: I wonder how is your answer different than mine (except it's less explanatory)